# retrieving data from a html select form with Play Framework

Tags: java, select, playframework

as the title say, i'm trying to retrieve the selected item from a html select form. I tried to do so with the following code but it doesn't work ! the city value's always NULL but the address field return correct value ...

The form.html:

```
#{extends '/Admin/admin.html' /}
 #{form @save(id)}

    #{ifErrors}
        <p class="error">
            Please correct these errors.
        </p>
    #{/ifErrors}

    <p>
        <label>Adresse</label>
        <input type="text" name="adress" value="${flash.adress}" id="adress" />
        <span class="error">#{error 'adress' /}
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Ville</label>
        <select size="1" >
            #{list items:cities, as:'city'}
                <option name="city" id="city" value="${flash.city}">${city}</option>
            #{/list}
        </select>
        <span class="error">#{error 'city' /}
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Publier l'annonce" />
    </p>

 #{/form}
```

the save method:

```
public static void save(long id, String adress, @Required Place city){ 
    System.out.println(city);
    Admin.index();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work like that, it should be like:

```
public static void save(long id, String adress, @Required String city){ 
    // in order or so I think...: get the city ID or whatever, process all the data and save
    System.out.println(city);
    Admin.index();
}
```

There's another way which I believe it's the one you are looking for:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers#POJOobjectbinding

Answer (score 6):

You must name your select tag not option tag and you must use the correct field :

```
<select size="1" name="city.id">
            #{list items:cities, as:'city'}
                <option value="${city.id}">${city.name}</option>
            #{/list}
</select>
```

See the doc for more information on binding : [Doc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/controllers#POJOobjectbinding)

Answer (score 0):

```
#{select 'city', value:C2, id:'select1'}
#{option 'C1'}City1#{/option}#{option 'C2'}City2#{/option}#{option 'C3'}City3#{/option}
#{/select}
```